# java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I updated my database from SQLite db to MySQL and I suddenly I get this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.

```java
public boolean isEnough(int quantity, String item) throws SQLException {
    boolean enough = false;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE Item_name='" + item + "'";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        int temp = rs.getInt(3);

        if (quantity > temp) {

            stmt.close();
            enough = false;
        } else if (quantity <= temp) {

            enough = true;
            int updatedStock = temp - quantity;
            String sql_1 = "UPDATE Stock SET Item_quantity ='" + updatedStock + "' WHERE Item_name ='" + item + "'";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql_1); //error here
            String sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE Item_name='" + item + "'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            System.out.println(rs);
            if (rs.next()) {
                int isZero = rs.getInt(3);
                if (isZero == 0) {
                    String sql_3 = "DELETE FROM Stock WHERE Item_name = '" + item + "'";
                    stmt.executeUpdate(sql_3);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Order Added\nItem is now out of Stock and removed from Stock database automatically.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    stmt.close();
    return enough;
}
```

I'm closing connection and statement after every update, but I have no idea how to fix this error. If I go back to SQLite db this error disappears. I'm new to MySQL, so pardon me if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing the problem, but an unrelated comment: don't use string concatenation to build your SQL statements, because those are vulnerable to SQL injection. You should be using placeholders - see e.g. https://bobby-tables.com/ where there are examples for Java.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. This code doesn't show where `stmt` is defined, but given it seems to be an instance field, and this method closes `stmt`, when the method (or another method using `stmt`) is called again, it likely results in `stmt` being closed. Possibly the SQLite JDBC driver plays it loose with the JDBC requirements, and allows a statement to be reused even after `close()` was called. I would suggest to make `stmt` a local variable. And as ndc85430 says: please learn to use parameterized statements properly, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.